# The version is increased although saveOrUpdate failed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, version

I have a table in database create by SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `s_supplier` ( <br/>
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,<br/>
  `code` varchar(32) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,<br/>
  `name` varchar(128) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,<br/>
  `version` int(11) NOT NULL default '0'<br/>
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),<br/>
  UNIQUE KEY `ui_uom_category_code` (`code`)<br/>
)
```

The database existing 2 row: 
(1, code1, name1, 1)
(2, code2, name2, 1)

Using spring-hibernate:
step 1: 
I load row 1 to the entity and then change the code to code2 (the same as row 2).
and then call
 **org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(entity);** 
--> It raises the exception 'duplicate code' --> OK

step 2: 
I change the code to code3  and then save again by above method --> It raises the exception 'optimistic exception the row was update or delete by other user' (I just test on single user) --> KO

After tracing I found that after step 1 the version automatically increasing 1 on the entity. I think it should not because happened exception.

My question:

> Is that the bug of spring framework or hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

Does not sound like a bug. I don't know is it clearly documented in Hibernate documentation, but behavior is consistent with JPA specification:

> ```
> Transaction rollback typically causes the persistence context to be in an 
> inconsistent state at the point of rollback. In particular, the state of 
> version attributes and generated state (e.g., generated primary keys) may
> be inconsistent.
> ```